# Variable not updated on class file and pass to main in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I try to update variable from another class file to main file but it wont update. I have a lot of variable need to set
Example below

var_global.py

```
BarCode1 = ""
BarCode2 = ""
BarCode3 = ""
BarCode4 = ""
BarCode5 = ""
BarCode6 = ""
BarCode7 = ""
```

Class_ServerThread.py

```
import var_global
from threading import Thread

class SocketServerThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    while True:
      var_global.Barcode1 = '100'
      var_global.Barcode2 = '200'
      var_global.Barcode3 = '300'
      var_global.Barcode4 = '400'
      var_global.Barcode5 = '500'
      var_global.Barcode6 = '600'
      var_global.Barcode7 = '700'
      break
```

Main.py

```
import var_global
from Class_ServerThread import SocketServerThread

ss = SocketServerThread()
ss.start()

try
  while True:
    print(var_global.Barcode1) # must show 100
    print(var_global.Barcode2) # must show 200
    print(var_global.Barcode3) # must show 300
    print(var_global.Barcode4) # must show 400
    print(var_global.Barcode5) # must show 500
    print(var_global.Barcode6) # must show 600
    print(var_global.Barcode7) # must show 700

finally:
  GPIO.cleanup()
```

Please help how to update variable value

Answer (score 0):

I move import var_global inside while True: on main.py & and Class_ServerThread.py. Its working now.

Class_ServerThread.py

```
from threading import Thread

class SocketServerThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    while True:
      import var_global
      var_global.Barcode1 = '100'
      var_global.Barcode2 = '200'
      var_global.Barcode3 = '300'
      var_global.Barcode4 = '400'
      var_global.Barcode5 = '500'
      var_global.Barcode6 = '600'
      var_global.Barcode7 = '700'
      break
```

Main.py

```
from Class_ServerThread import SocketServerThread

ss = SocketServerThread()
ss.start()

try
  while True:
    import var_global
    print(var_global.Barcode1) # must show 100
    print(var_global.Barcode2) # must show 200
    print(var_global.Barcode3) # must show 300
    print(var_global.Barcode4) # must show 400
    print(var_global.Barcode5) # must show 500
    print(var_global.Barcode6) # must show 600
    print(var_global.Barcode7) # must show 700

finally:
  GPIO.cleanup()
```